# Excel Paste String To Different Cells

Tags: angular, excel

I have an Angular application with a table. I'm trying to copy all of the headers and paste them into an Excel file, where each string is in a separate cell. For example, "Name, Age, Gender" should have "Name" in cell A1, "Age" in cell B1, "Gender" in cell C1, and so on. I want to accomplish this without manipulating the existing data in the file and without creating a new file with the headers already included.

Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve this?
Thanks.

Already tried using tabs and looking for special chars to skip to the next cell without any luck.

Comment: Text to column?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.